# How to print the values of parameters passed into a function

Tags: python, function, printing, arguments

I don’t know how to retrieve, store and print the values of parameters passed into a function. I do know that many posts are related to this question, but I couldn't find anything that matches the simple thing I would like to do.

Let’s take a very simple example:

```
def times(value, power):
    return value**power
```

If I run this function and then write:

```
x = times(2.72, 3.1)
print(f'Result of calculation is: {x: .6f}')
```

then the output will be:

```
Result of calculation is:  22.241476
```

OK, but this is not what I would like to have; I would like to be able to print the **result**, the **value** and the **power**, and have the following lines as output, preferably using a `print` as above; something like `print(f’some text here: {something}’)`…

**Desired output:**

```
Result of calculation is:  22.241476
Value passed to function was:  2
Power passed to function was:  3
```

What is the most effective way to do that?

Comment: Since you *know* the parameters you just passed in, presumably you can just print them. Failing that, your function can return a tuple of `(value**power, value, power)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question appears to be asking about accessing the function's namespace, not just printing the value of the variables. If the namespace concept is new to you, I recommend reading the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and [Real Python's](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/) blog post on Namespace's in Python. Let's look at a few ways to do what you are asking.

Printing the values is straightforward:

```py
def times(value, power):
    print(f"Value passed to function was:  {value}")
    print(f"Power passed to function was:  {power}")
    print(f'Result of calculation is: {x: .6f}')
```

If you need to print it out the way you describe in your question, the values should be returned. This can be accomplished by updating your function to:

```py
def times(value, power):
    return value, power, value**power

v, p, result = times(2,3)

print(f'Result of calculation is: {result: .6f}')
print(f"Value passed to function was:  {v}")
print(f"Power passed to function was:  {p}")
```

However, returning parameters seems a little odd since one would assume you as the developer can capture those values elsewhere in your code. If you want to view the variables and their values for a given namespace, use the corresponding function. For viewing the `value` and `power` variables, which live in the function `times()` local namespace, use `locals()` which returns a dictionary object that is a copy of the current local namespace.

```
def times(value, power):
    print(locals())
    return value**power

>>> times(5, 4)
{'value': 5, 'power': 4}
625
```

If the variables are defined in the global namespace, (keep in mind global variables should be used with care) you can use `globals()` to look up the value in the global namespace:

```py
VALUE = 2
POWER = 3
def times(value=VALUE, power=POWER):
    return value**power

>>> globals()['VALUE']
2
>>> globals()['POWER']
3
```

I hope this helps you figure out how to accomplish what you are working on. I recommend taking some time to read about how Python views and manages namespaces. If you want to watch a video, check out this [PyCon talk by Raymond Hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8moWQ1561FY) on object oriented programming 4 different ways.

Comment: Perfectly fitting my request

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first store the parameters in variables in the code that calls the function.

Assuming the function 'times' is defined.

```
a = 2.72
b = 3.1
x = times(a, b)
print(f'Result of calculation is: {x: .6f}')
print(f'Value passed to function was: {a}')
print(f'Power passed to function was: {b}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just add more "print" lines.

So the code would look something like this:

```
def times(value, power):
    print(f'Result of calculation is: {x: .6f}')
    print(f'Value passed to function was: {value}')
    print(f'Power passed to function was: {power}')
```

and then you can just pass the values into the function like so:

```
times(2.72, 3.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. It uses the concept of closure (google it). Hope it is helpful.

```
def times():
    value = float(input('Enter a value:'))
    power = float(input('Enter a power: '))

    def raise_to_power():
        return value ** power
    print(
        f'Result of calculation is: {raise_to_power(): .6f}\nValue passed to function was: {value}\nPower passed to function was: {power}')


times()
```

Comment: What's the point of defining `raise_to_power` at all?